# REST API with OneDrive API

Tags: onedrive

Is it possible to create REST Api, which is able to manage the Office365 user's files on OneDrive? I would like to use this api from different application.

[image]

Comment: look at onedrive rest api:  https://dev.onedrive.com/readme.htm

Comment: Yes I know the OneDrive API, I analyze it for a few days and it seems to me that such a scenario is impossible.

Comment: I don't think this question is complete enough to answer. Nothing in the picture looks impossible / hard to complete with Microsoft Graph / AAD authentication. Your REST API layer would just map between the internal API your application expects and the Microsoft Graph API to upload/share files. You can manage authentication using the [methods defined here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/), or you could role your own authentication and manage the refresh tokens for users yourself.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for you answer. Great to read that this is possible, but I can’t find helpful samples nor implemetation. It's especially important because we talk about quite important things as security.
There is an ASP.NET Core web application that authenticates Azure AD users and calls a web API using OAuth 2.0 access tokens:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore
Could you create new branch and use OneDrive Api in TodoListService? This will be very helpful for community